# How to design a REST API

Tags: api, rest, schema, api-design

I am building a metadata platform for a broadcaster. It exposes a REST API to write data to the DB.

I struggle with the design of the endpoint boundaries. There is a wide range of options to split the API controller model so that the API producers can write data in either normalized or denormalized form. I am not sure what a widely accepted design is so that the platform provides the best possible developer experience.

[image: The Domain Model]

I have modeled both extremes with a PUT request for updates. Which one is more usable?

## Normalised

**PUT /episodes**

```
{
    "season" : 1,
    "episodeInSeason" : 2,
    "texts" : [
       "#ref TextId"
    ],  
    "variants" : [
       "#ref VariantId"
    ]
}
```

**PUT /variants**

```
{
    "texts" : [
        "#ref TextId"
    ], 
    "assets" : [
        "#ref AssetId"
    ]
}
```

**PUT /assets**

```
{
    "texts" : [
        "#ref TextId"
    ],
    "renditions" : [{
        "fps": 60.0 
    }],
    "markIn" : "#ref MarkerId",
    "markOut" : "#ref MarkerId"
}
```

**PUT /texts**

```
{
    "title": "foo",
    "lang" : "en"
}
```

**PUT /renditions**

```
{
    "fps": 60.0 
}
```

**PUT /markers**

```
{
    "position" : 2.2
}
```

## Denormalised

**PUT /episodes**

```
{
    "season" : 1,
    "episodeInSeason" : 2,
    "texts" : [{
        "title": "foo",
        "lang" : "en"
    }],  
    "variants" : [{
        "texts" : [{
            "title": "foo",
            "lang" : "en"
        }],
        "assets" : [{
            "texts" : [{
                "title": "foo",
                "lang" : "en"
            }],
            "renditions" : [{
                "fps": 60.0 
            }],
            "markIn" : {
                "position" : 1.0
            },
            "markOut" :  {
                "position" : 2.2
            }
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Work it out in [OpenAPI Specification](https://swagger.io/specification/) to provide the best developer experience.